# kdb q - save partitions in parallel

Tags: kdb

I have a function that "retrieves" (in this case just creates) a table and stores it in a new partition

```
npertable:100000;
dbname:`:partdb;

newpart:{[date]
    firstofmonth:"d"$"m"$date;
    table:([]date:npertable?firstofmonth+til 25;acc:npertable?`C123`C132`C321`C121`C131;c:npertable?til 100);
    table:`date`acc xasc table;
    partname:`$(("/" sv (string dbname;string "m"$date;enlist "t")),enlist "/");
    partname set .Q.en[dbname;table];
 };
```

Let's assume it takes a "long" time to create the `table` inside the function (e.g. a lot of rows). Now, I cannot use this method on different threads

`newpart peach 2018.03.01 2018.04.01 2018.05.01`

because of

```
ERROR: 'noupdate: `. `sym
```

which isn't so surprising because it probably cannot asynchronously update the sym file.

Is there a way to store partitions in parallel at all in kdb?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to re-logic your function and break it down into smaller steps. I'd separate the enumeration from the setting to disk firstly - that way allowing you to enumerate all tables' sym columns in the main thread, and then setting the enumerated data to disk in threads. Note - this will likely only be beneficial if you are parallelizing disk io in the first place.

```
npertable:100000;
dbname:`:partdb;

createTab:{[datep]
    firstofmonth:"d"$"m"$datep;
    table:([]date:npertable?firstofmonth+til 25;acc:npertable?`C123`C132`C321`C121`C131;c:npertable?til 100);
    delete date from `date`acc xasc table
    };

createPath:{[datep]
    .Q.dd[dbname;(datep;`t;`)]
    };

enumTab:{[t]
    .Q.en[dbname;t]
    };

setInParallel:{[datep]
    enummedTabs:{enumTab createTab x} each datep;
    paths:createPath each datep;
    .[set;] peach flip (paths;enummedTabs)
    };
```

Now you can run setInParallel against a list of dates

```
bash> q code.q -s 5
q)setInParallel .z.d-til 5
`:partdb/2018.04.25/t/`:partdb/2018.04.24/t/`:partdb/2018.04.23/t/`..
```

Some notes just to be aware:

- You don't need the date column when setting a table to a date partition. You certainly can have it, but it becomes the virtual date column when q maps in the date directories so no need for it. Hence why I delete the date column on creation.
- `.Q.dd` is a very useful function for creating paths (easier than building strings). Note how I create a path from the root hdb, date parameter, table name, and a leading ` (which signifies the leading / (i.e. dir) when creating a path)
- The `createTab` function I took from your `newpart` function. You cast the inputted date to a month and then back to a date to get the first date of the month. This may be what you are looking for but just so you are aware you will never be able to set to dates other than the first of the month, even if your inputted param is 2018.01.02 for example.

HTH,
Sean

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it relies on you knowing the full universe of possible symbols ahead of the writedown. If, as it appears, these are some sort of account ID, you may well know all possible values before saving I suppose. In this case, you can create the sym vector first in the main thread, and then peach the write down, performing the enumeration with the [$](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/enums/#enum) operator, which doesn't update the global variable. For example:

```
npertable:100000;
dbname:`:partdb;
sym:`C123`C132`C321`C121`C131;    //create sym vector
(` sv dbname,`sym) set sym;       //save sym vector in db

newpart:{[date]
    firstofmonth:"d"$"m"$date;
    table:([]date:npertable?firstofmonth+til 25;acc:npertable?`C123`C132`C321`C121`C131;c:npertable?til 100);
    table:`date`acc xasc table;
    partname:`$(("/" sv (string dbname;string "m"$date;enlist "t")),enlist "/");
    table:@[table;`acc;`sym$];    //enumerate acc column with hardcoded column name
    partname set table;           //table already enumerated, don't use .Q.en
 };

newpart peach 2018.03.01 2018.04.01 2018.05.01
```

Note that in this case the column name to be enumerated is hardcoded - in a more flexible implementation, you might use some modification of `.Q.en` to identify columns which require enumeration and perform this for all necessary columns automatically.

Of course, if in your real `newpart` function there is a chance of *new* values being added to the `acc` field, this poses a larger problem. Ideally, you would want to know about any new values in the main thread before performing the `peach`, so you can add any new values to the `sym` vector.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - found an older online post from Kx that suggests that my approach below is not a good idea: "A handle must not be used concurrently between threads as there is no locking around a socket descriptor". But I'll keep it here for reference

It may be possible (though I haven't tested thoroughly) to set up a separate writer process to handle the writing, then you peach and send the data to the writer which will in turn do the enumeration and writing. Something along the lines of:

```
{neg[h](`runThisFunc;onThisData);(neg h)[]} peach 1 2
```

The flush is required I believe. Newer versions of kdb can allow large amounts of data to be sent via IPC so that part shouldn't be a problem.

Again I haven't ever done this in a production setting but in theory I can't think of why you couldn't.